# How can I avoid form.is_valid() flagging an empty field as an error in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a template that is used for updating a table. However, the user can choose to update one field or all of them. The chances are that he won't be updating all the fields, so I want to be able to run `form.is_valid()`, but I don't want to have it return false if there are empty fields in the form which there will almost certainly be.

I don't want to use `required=False` in the form, because there is another template that uses the same form where the user must fill in almost all the fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would probably be to subclass your form and set `required=False` in the subclass, either repeating the field definition or doing it in `__init__`. Otherwise, you could set `required=False` in your view, eg:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.METHOD == 'POST':
        form = SomeFormClass(request.POST)
        form.fields['fieldname'].required = False
        if form.is_valid():
            # etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. That worked. Sorry it doesn't let me upvote your answer as this is the first time I ever used Stack Overflow.